# Rails activerecord select records by count of has_many through relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Each Character has_many Conversations (through: :chats) and each Conversation has_many Characters (through: :chats). A Character may have one Conversation involving only one other Character (two participants), and other Conversations involving the same Character and other Characters (three or more participants).

I'm trying to construct a query that selects only the two-participant conversation.

The following gives a missing FROM-clause entry error. I've tried many permutations and can't get it right.

**Character**

```
has_many :chats,  foreign_key: "character_id",
                  dependent: :destroy

has_many :conversations, through: :chats, source: :conversation
```

**Conversation**

```
has_many :chats,  foreign_key: "conversation_id",
                  dependent: :destroy

has_many :characters, through: :chats, source: :character

def self.FindOneToOneConversation(sender, recipient)
  @sender    = Character.find_by(callsign: sender)
  @recipient = Character.find_by(callsign: recipient)
  @senderConversations = @sender.conversations
  @senderAndRecipientConversation = @senderConversations.joins(:characters)
                                                        .where(characters: {id: @recipient.id})
                                                        .having("COUNT(character.id) < 3")

  return @senderAndRecipientConversation.first # .first because @senderAndRecipientConversations is a collection

end
```

**Logs:**

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "character"
LINE 1: ..._id" = $1 AND "characters"."id" = $2 HAVING COUNT(character....
                                                             ^

: SELECT  "conversations".* FROM "conversations" INNER JOIN "chats" "chats_conversations_join" ON "chats_conversations_join"."conversation_id" = "conversations"."id" INNER JOIN "characters" ON "characters"."id" = "chats_conversations_join"."character_id" INNER JOIN "chats" ON "conversations"."id" = "chats"."conversation_id" WHERE "chats"."character_id" = $1 AND "characters"."id" = $2 HAVING COUNT(character.id) < 3  ORDER BY "conversations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "character"
LINE 1: ..._id" = $1 AND "characters"."id" = $2 HAVING COUNT(character....
```

I hoped this would work, but it gives this error:

Missing FROM-clause entry for table "conversations"

```
@senderAndRecipientConversation = Conversation.select('*, COUNT(chats.character_id)')
                                              .from("(#{@senderConversations.to_sql}) AS sender_conversations")
                                              .joins("
                                        INNER JOIN     chats
                                        ON             sender_conversations.id = chats.conversation_id
                                        GROUP BY       chats.conversation_id
                                        HAVING COUNT(chats.character_id) < 3
                                        ")
```

In response to the first answer, the following is flawed and I can't see why - it finds all conversations involving the recipient, not just the one-to-one conversation:

```
@senderAndRecipientConversation = @senderConversations.joins(:characters)
                                                      .where(characters: {id: @recipient.id})
                                                      .group('conversations.id')
                                                      .having("COUNT(characters.id) < 3")
```

Comment: can you show us the full stack trace of the error ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `GROUP` records before using `HAVING` clause on them. Try something like the following

```
@senderConversations.joins(:characters)
  .where(characters: {id: @recipient.id})
  .group('character_id')
  .having("COUNT(character.id) < 3")
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't get this working. If you want to count character.id you have to group by something else no? I tried grouping by conversations.id but it returns more than one record.